# How to extract date from filename on Windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, batch, filesystems, date-time

I need to do hand formatting date values for some files.

I have just extracted 6000 photos/videos from an application and they are all named following this structure, with different dates and times for each photo: `2016-12-09_10.13.39.JPG`.

In spite of this, the files display the wrong *date created* and *date modified* values, showing today's date instead of the date that they were created and modified.

I am wondering if there is a way for me to extract the name of the file into Windows date format [Australia], something like this: `12/09/2016 1:39 PM`, and then format the values to the date created and modified fields?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @phuclv [who unfortunately won't get pinged cos he's not in the comment thread] Making spurious edits to a closed question ruins the chances of the OP ever getting it re-opened. Only the first edit pushes the question to the review queue.. in this case your underwhelming format edit.

Comment: @Tetsujin why? you can still vote to reopen it

Comment: @phuclv - because there was nothing in the edit that warranted it reopening; hence my first comment. It will never appear again in the review queue, so the opportunity has been lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following PowerShell script

```powershell
$culture = [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-AU')
foreach ($f in ls *.jpg) {
    $d = [datetime]::ParseExact($f.BaseName, "yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss", $culture)
    $f.CreationTime = $d
    $f.LastWriteTime = $d
}
```

It'll loop through all files in the current folder, parse the date in file name and then set the creation and modified time to that time. `$culture` is actually unnecessary in this case and you can change the last parameter of `[datetime]::ParseExact` to `$null`

If you want to do this for all files in subfolders as well then change the `foreach` header to `ls -R *.jpg`